# Unable to Install mysqlclient on dreamhost server

Tags: mysql, django, dreamhost

I'm trying to get a mysql database set up on my dreamhost shared server but it seems I can't proceed without mysqlclient. When I try `pip install mysqlclient` however i get

> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall
>   -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/eptaba/aeromembers.com/AeroMembers_env/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG
>
> _mysql.c:32:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>
> #include "Python.h"
>
> ```
>                 ^
> ```
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

I've seen in other answers that these types of problems can be solved with

```
apt-get install python3.4-dev
```

But being on dreamhost's shared server product i'm not able to execute that command. Is there anything else I can do to either get mysqlclient or set up my mysql without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by installing Python 3.6 and using that in my virtualenv instead of Python 3.4. Afterwards I was able to `pip install mysqlclient`